# How to assign PartitionKey to CosmosDB queries using Node.js SDK v3.5.2

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I upgraded CosmosDB Node.js SDK from 2.1.5 to 3.5.2 and the following code is no longer working.

```
client.items.query(myQuery, { partitionKey: "MyPartitionKey" }).toArray()
```

I changed the code to the following but it still does not transpile (typescript) and apparently the cause is that `FeedOptions` no longer contains `partitionKey` property!

```
client.items.query(myQuery,{ partitionKey: "MyPartitionKey" }).fetchAll()
```

I looked it up in the internet but could not find an up to date example.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out in v3 of the sdk there is no need to explicitly assign `partitionkey` value. If `partitionkey` engages in `where` clause, it will automatically be regarded.

[githib issue reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/6841)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any up-to-date example from MS or github source code which is really challenging.

There is no any `partitionkey` property in FeedOptions class in the cosmos db node sdk v3 any more.After my deep research on the github source code of `FeedOptions`,i found that it extends another interface `SharedOptions`:

[image]

And it contains `initialHeaders` property so that i'm supposed that we could set partition key value following the [REST API Header Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/common-cosmosdb-rest-request-headers).

[image]

Anyway,please refer to my working code:

```
const feedOptions = {
        initialHeaders: {"x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey": '["a"]'}
      };
   const queryIterator = await container.items.query(querySpec,feedOptions);
    while (queryIterator.hasMoreResults()) {
        console.log(await queryIterator.fetchNext());
    }
```

Surely,you could replace it with `.fetchAll()` method.